# Channel Advisor not updaing order information

Tags: php, channeladvisor

I am using channel advisor UpdateOrderList operation.

```
$request = array('accountID' => 'acount id',
 'updateOrderSubmitList'=> array(
 "OrderID"=>$ca_id,
 "ShippingInfo"=>array(.... )
 )
);
```

My result is success. But no change in order shipping info. Also order status is unshipped as we can update only unshipped orders.

Answer (score 0):

After too much R&D i got solution. updateOrderSubmitList accept multiple orders to be updated. Therefore We have to pass multiple orders i.e. array of arrays.

```
$request = array('accountID' => 'acount id',
 'updateOrderSubmitList'=> array(
   array(
  "OrderID"=>$ca_id1,
   "ShippingInfo"=>array(.... )
   ),
   array(
  "OrderID"=>$ca_id2,
   "ShippingInfo"=>array(.... )
   ),
  )
);
```